# C++ Decorate basic_iostream classes

Tags: c++, std, fstream, iostream

I want to do something like the following code shows:

```
class foo
{
private:
    std::fstream* m_stream;

public:
    foo(std::fstream* stream) : m_stream(stream) { }

    foo& write(char const* s, std::streamsize count)
    {
        if (/*condition*/)
        {
            m_stream->write(s, count);
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }

        return *this;
    }

    foo& read(char* s, std::streamsize count)
    {
        if (/*condition*/)
        {
            m_stream->read(s, count);
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }

        return *this;
    }
};
```

I would need to add the same behavior to all similar methods (e.g. `put`). This shouldn't be applied to file streams only, but all other stream classes. Is there any easy way to allow these functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of the formatted output operators (`operator<<`) write directly to the underlying stream buffer. What you need to do in order to accomplish this in a general fashion is derive a class from std::basic_streambuf that forwards all data to another std::basic_streambuf, and then optionally create a minimal std::basic_ostream implementation to make using your stream buffer easier.

I wouldn't say this is particularly easy, though, but it's the only way to do this in a way that can affect all stream types.

Here is an example of a minimal stream buffer that forwards to another stream buffer (and performs some meaningless transformation just to demonstrate what you can do), and an accompanying stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>

template<typename CharType, typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharType> >
class ForwardingStreamBuf : public std::basic_streambuf<CharType, Traits>
{
public:
    typedef Traits traits_type;
    typedef typename traits_type::int_type int_type;
    typedef typename traits_type::pos_type pos_type;
    typedef typename traits_type::off_type off_type;

    ForwardingStreamBuf(std::basic_streambuf<CharType, Traits> *baseStreamBuf)
        : _baseStreamBuf(baseStreamBuf)
    {
    }

protected:
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c = traits_type::eof())
    {
        if( _baseStreamBuf == NULL )
            return traits_type::eof();

        if( traits_type::eq_int_type(c, traits_type::eof()) )
            return traits_type::not_eof(c);
        else
        {
            CharType ch = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
            if( ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'z' )
                ch++; // Do some meaningless transformation
            return _baseStreamBuf->sputc(ch);
        }
    }

    virtual int sync()
    {
        if( _baseStreamBuf == NULL )
            return -1;
        else
            return _baseStreamBuf->pubsync();
    }
private:
    std::basic_streambuf<CharType, Traits> *_baseStreamBuf;
};

template<typename CharType, typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharType> >
class ForwardingStream : public std::basic_ostream<CharType, Traits>
{
public:
    ForwardingStream(std::basic_ostream<CharType, Traits> &stream)
        : std::basic_ostream<CharType, Traits>(NULL), _buffer(stream.rdbuf())
    {
        this->init(&_buffer);
    }

    ForwardingStreamBuf<CharType, Traits>* rdbuf() const
    {
        return &_buffer;
    }
private:
    ForwardingStreamBuf<CharType, Traits> _buffer;
};
```

This can be used very simply:

```
int main()
{
    ForwardingStream<char> test(std::cout);
    test << "Foo" << std::endl;
}
```

Which would output `Gpp`. I hope that helps you on your way.

Comment: How could I do that for non-virtual functions like `eback`, `egptr`, etc.?

Comment: Deriving from `streambuf` is not the correct solution here.  He'd got the basic idea right: define an independent class which doesn't derive from anything.  And provide a templated `operator<<` for that.

Comment: You don't need to override those. The only thing you need to override for basic functionality is `overflow` (if using output only). I've updated my answer with a basic sample of a forwarding stream buffer.

Comment: How would I used it with (e.g.) fstream class?

Comment: @Sven: I also need to "catch" everything that is read before it's actually read.

Comment: `fstream file; ForwardingStream<char> fw(file);`. For reading you'd need to do something similar to the `underflow` method as what I did with `overflow` here. Depending on what you're actually trying to do James's suggestion might be more appropriate though.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I would like to set just a new `rdbuf` to the stream. Is there no chance to achieve the same result with derivation?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
   template <class Stream>
    class DecoratedStream {
    public:
      DecoratedStream(Stream* stream) : m_stream(stream) {}

      DecoratedStream& write(const char* data, int count) {
        m_stream->write(data, count);
      }

    };
```

Comment: Not necessary.  Just use `iostream`, rather than `fstream`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to decorate methods of any `iostream`. So just make your decorator take an `iostream` as decoratee (as opposed to an `fstream`, which is a subclass of `iostream`).

Comment: Except quite a lot of `operator<<` functions output directly to the `std::basic_streambuf` used by the stream, and would therefore bypass this modification entirely.

Comment: @Sven: Is that so? I was not aware of that. However, in that case it the entire approach of the OP would be invalid, because decorating the streams would not suffice, no matter how you do it.

Comment: yes, I had to do something similar recently to add line wrapping functionality to any stream. The only way to do it is to derive a `std::basic_streambuf` that wraps another `std::basic_streambuf`. Inheriting from `std::basic_ostream` just won't help in most cases. That's what I said in my answer.

Comment: @Sven How the `operator<<` functions work is irrelevant, because they don't get called until he actually outputs to the decorated stream.

Answer (score 0):

Having pointer inside a structure as your current approach is dangerous and error prone. Instead just derive such `stream` classes and implement basic constructors and wrap around your custom methods such as `write()`.

```
template<typename StreamType>
class foo : StreamType
{
  // wrapper constructors supporting StreamType() constructors
  foo& write(char const* s, std::streamsize count)
  {
    //...
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
foo<fstream> obj;
obj.write(...);
```

Comment: Do not derive.  Almost none of the functions of `iostream` are virtual, so you can't override them.

Comment: @James, no need to override them as, we are simply going to use them as functionality extensions. There will be never a case of `Base &b = Derived();` for this scenario. It's just a wrapper to add more functionality like custom `read/write`. Rest of all the methods will be used directly from the base class.

Comment: @lammilind In which case, I'd recommend simple free functions, which take an `std::istream` or an `std::ostream` as argument.  No need for any additional complications.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution for this sort of problem is to use templates.  There
aren't that many functions in an `std::istream` or and `std::ostream
which need covering, and a good template member for`<<`and`>>`should
cover a lot of the cases.  In most of the cases I've done this, I've
only offerred`<<`or`>>`.  (Generally speaking, I've not needed
bidirectional streams.)

As for handling other types of streams, just use `std::iostream` instead
of `std::fstream`.  (In general, except when opening files, you
shouldn't see the `fstream` part.)