# Derive from ostream or ostream_iterator to make a stream pretty printer in C++?

Tags: c++

I have code which dumps a representation of complex objects to a stream.  The representation uses open and close curly brackets to denote the start and end of nested objects.  Rather than pretty print the representation format, I feel it's better to leave all whitespace out of the raw output and implement pretty printing, if desired, as a decorator pattern.

The pretty print algorithm is simply: examine next char to output, if it is a close brace, output newline + close brace + newline.  Else just output the char.

I could implement this decorator as a class derived from ostream_iterator or as a class derived from ostream.  Which is more commonly done?  Are there any downsides to creating an ostream wrapper?

Comment: According to what metrics? What's your definition of "more correct"?

Comment: Good point I'll edit the question.

Comment: I don't think I'd do either. What's wrong with making a `<<` overload or two?

Comment: Actually I do have << overloads as well, but I'm using those for "quick and dirty print this" whereas the "dump representation" methods output the structure in a well-defined way that can be compared to expected values in assertions in unit tests.  (I can't assert object == some other object because that operator has a different meaning than value equality for some of the objects.)

Comment: Secondly if I just did << overloads it wouldn't be implementing the pretty-printing in a second step.  See the requirement of my question is specifically "given a stream of characters containing braces, output another stream of characters with the braces surrounded by newlines."  Whether that stream of characters got produced by << overloads or other methods is immaterial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason where it is advisable to derive from `std::ostream` is when using the derived class to construct an `std::streambuf` and initialize the the base `std::ostream` with it. I don't think there is ever a reason to derive from `std::ostream_iterator<...>` at all.

Instead you'd derive from `std::streambuf` and override `overflow()` to do whatever filter operation you want to do. For convenience you might then derive from `std::ostream` to construct a convenience stream.

Comment: Indeed, this is the solution I ended up going with, and it is working.  The accepted answer on this question gives some example code, which I then simplified by making mine not use a template (since I only needed it to deal with one character type): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384860/c-decorate-basic-iostream-classes